# Как вызвать метод doDelete или doPut в сервлете из jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

Всем привет!

Не могу понять как вызываются методы doDelete и doPut в сервлете, если в <<*form>> <<method*>> jsp можно указать только get или post? **Я могу удалить то, что мне нужно с помощью метода get в jsp и doGet в сервлете, но нужно научиться использовать doDelete и doPut.** Открывал даже Шилдта, но он как на зло писал что-то типа: "Ну все мы рассматривать не будем, рассмотри только doGet и doPost". Когда пытаюсь использовать doDelete вылетает 405 эксепшн, скрин тоже приложу.

[image: delete.jsp]

[image: DeleteServlet]

[image: 405]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Нужно без спринга, как люди работали с doDelete до появления Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно зачем вам это делать в форме используя его механизмы. Хотите удалить используйте js и XMLHttpRequest вызывайте любой метод с нужными вам параметрами.

Вот [пример](https://overcoder.net/q/3613757/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-jsp-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-ajax) использования.

А вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms) почему это так

Comment: То есть чтобы вызвать doDelete нужно использовать js? Других вариантов нет? Или есть вариант проще?

Comment: А чем этот вариант сложен? Вы поймите форма сама по себе не вызовет delete она не для этого создавалась https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp#:~:text=The%20method%20attribute%20specifies%20how,URL%20in%20name%2Fvalue%20pairs

Comment: А вы хотите именно этого. Вызвать delete реквест из форм submit.